# Why Taiwanese passports are recognised but Taiwan is not?

Tags: china, taiwan, identity-document

I was reading about current situation of Peoples Republic of China and Republic of China. I know Republic of China lost its seat in Un on behalf of the Peoples Republic of China. I know most countries no longer recognise Republic of China. But what is interesting, is a fact that Republic of China even without recognition, can issue passports that are valid for travel.

I always thought you need to have some kind of recognition to be able to issue valid passports

Comment: Welcome to politics SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help], and join us in [chat] if you feel like it.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong.  There is no need for some kind of recognition.

Answer (score 1):

It is sort of like the HongKong SAR passport: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong_Special_Administrative_Region_passport. Although technically under the rule of the Party, HK's administration is still a bit different--the agreement about keeping the democratic system in place for 50 years: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong_Basic_Law. So to show this difference, HK have a special passport, different than the one used by mainland China. I guess there are agreements between mainland and Taiwan about this issue and that Taiwan will use Republic of China name to accomodate that "one China" claim.

Comment: The situation is not quite the same. HKSAR travel documents are issued by approval of Beijing in the Sino-British Joint Declaration. However, Beijing denies that the RoC has competency to issue passports, and does not recognise these documents. There is certainly no agreement on this. The closest the two sides come to agreement was allowing Chinese residents of either place to enter the other. For Taiwanese to enter the PRC, they must do so under a bespoke travel document issued by the PRC called a "Mainland Travel Permit". The PRC quietly ignores whether other states recognize RoC passports.